# How to verify my PC is legacy BIOS with no support of EFI?

Tags: boot, bios, mbr, dualboot, legacy

I want to verify that my old PC is legacy BIOS/MBR only. (Note this is dual boot).
My motherboard is `Gigabyte Technology GA-890-FXA-UD5`. Checking `msinfo32.exe` it reports.

```
BIOS Version/Date Award Software Inc. 
SMBIOS version 2.4
```

Checking the file `C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log` it mentions `Detected boot environment: BIOS`.

On restart if I press `DEL` I go inside the BIOS menu (CMOS Setup Utility) and I don't see any boot option.

What else do I need to check to verify that my system is legacy boot (ie. BOOT & MBR)?

This is in relation to a warning I get when trying to install latest Kubuntu version without touching my existing Windows installation and dual boot.
The warning is:

```
No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot syccessfully and the installation process may fail.  
Please go back and add an EFI System Partition or continue at your own risk.
```

I want to be sure what is the Windows installation mode in my PC

My `msinfo32.exe` summary

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151205/discussion-on-question-by-jim-how-to-verify-my-pc-is-legacy-bios-with-no-support); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.